# hhline erases table border

Tags: tables, color, hhline

I have created a colored table, and I have a problem with \hhline. As you can see in the picture below, the hhline overwrites the left border of the table. How can I fix that?

(using cline is not an option, because it does not work well with colored tables).

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{2}{MidnightBlue!10}{white}
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
 \colorbox{MidnightBlue!30}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\rowcolor{MidnightBlue!30} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{test1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{test2}} \\ 
 \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|}
\rowcolor{MidnightBlue!30} & & & & \\
\rowcolor{MidnightBlue!30} \multirow{-3}{*}{test3} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\shortstack{test1\\test}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\shortstack{test2\\test}}  & \multirow{-2}{*}{\shortstack{test1\\test}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\shortstack{test2\\test}} \\
\hline 
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}\endgroup
\caption{\textbf{test}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Probably writing `\hhline{|~|-|-|-|-|}` solves it.

Comment: it 's not that hhline erased anything, you did not specify a border at that point

Answer (score 1):

For information, here is a way to construct that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You won't have rules which seem to vanish in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[vlines]
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{MidnightBlue!30}{1,2,3}
    \rowcolors{3}{MidnightBlue!10}{}
\Body
    \hline
    \Block{3-1}{text3} & \Block{1-2}{\textbf{test1}} && \Block{1-2}{\textbf{test2}} \\ 
    \Hline
    & \Block{2-1}{test1\\test} & \Block{2-1}{test2\\test}  & \Block{2-1}{test1\\test} & \Block{2-1}{test2\\test} \\ \\
    \hline 
    test & test & test & test & test \\
    test & test & test & test & test \\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Can you explain how exactly I could use this package? I am using Overleaf.

Comment: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`